# how to make div invisible on page called by ajax request

Tags: javascript

I can make div visible invisible on the same page using:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").style.display = "none";
```

By my main page is `index.php`. Whe user click button it load tge page  `url.php` using ajax call and content of url.php is appear on same page index.php in

Now on `url.php` I have `<div>` which should appear after button click.

on index.php

```
<body onload="show1()">
```

and show1() is

```
function show1(){
   //alert("hi");
document.getElementById("txtHint").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "none";
    }
```

Button on url.php page

```
<input type="submit" onclick="show2();" value="view div" > View Div </input>
```

and show() is

```
function show2(){
   //alert("hi");
document.getElementById("txtHint").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "block";
    }
```

I also tried by keeping show1 and show2 on url.php but no change.
div does not become invisible anyhow.

Comment: this should work. please put your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can debug and help

Comment: ok, but how this will work? I am trying to make it invisible in `index.php` on load event. But when `index.php` is loaded both `div` dont exist as they are on `url.php`.

Comment: Add style='display:none;' to the div in url.php

Comment: I still don't 100% understand the scenario, what is the code that runs when you click the button? Is url.php's content loaded into a div on index.php?

Comment: @Gavriel: Yes, entire content of url.php page loaded into the div on index.php. And the url.php page contents the div that I want to make invisible when it is loaded!

Comment: then do what Salim suggested

Comment: @Gavriel: Yes done. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it will help you

index.php

```
<span id='view_port'></span><br />
<input type="button" id="load_url" value="Load url.php" />

<script>
$("#load_url").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"url.php",
        success:function(response) {
            $("#view_port").html(response);
            $("#load_url").hide();
        }
    }); 
});

function show2() {
   //alert("hi");
    document.getElementById("txtHint").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

url.php

```
<div id='txtHint' style="display:none">This the div txtHint</div><br />
<div id='d1' style="display:none">This the div d1</div><br />
<input type="button" onclick="show2();" value="view div" >
```

Comment: jazakallah Salim, I think this sort of question is not asked and will help other. Upvote it if you think so.